# Convert a Json to csv using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a json file in the below format that I need to convert to csv in python.

```
{
  "data": {
    "clientApplicationRsaKeyss": [
      {
        "clientId": "abc-efg",
        "createdOn": "2021-02-26T08:45:43.2746397Z"
      },
      {
        "clientId": "xyz-lmn",
        "createdOn": "2022-05-23T16:11:59.435729Z"
      },
]
}
}
```

I need to convert the above into a csv with the below fields:

```
clientID          createdon
abc-efg          2021-02-26T08:45:43.2746397Z
xyz-lmn          2022-05-23T16:11:59.435729Z
```

How do I do this using python / dataframe?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Convert JSON to DataFrame, then DataFrame to CSV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a pandas DataFrame to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505055/save-dataframe-as-csv-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to do

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(json.load(open("test.json"))["data"]["clientApplicationRsaKeyss"])
>>> df 
  clientId                     createdOn
0  abc-efg  2021-02-26T08:45:43.2746397Z
1  xyz-lmn   2022-05-23T16:11:59.435729Z
>>> df.to_csv(".....", index=False)
```