# How to put csv data into an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I put a csv file via pandas into excel.
Reading csv is fine

```
QTH = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\SLA.csv")
ws = wb.sheets["mySheet"]
ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = QTH
```

The result is bad, since python write csv stuff into one line in excel.
With print(QTH) the data looked fine in python.

I need just the dataframe without the csv stuff, to put it into excel.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505055/save-dataframe-as-csv-in-python ?

Comment: will this work for you ->
```ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = f"{QTH}"```

Comment: f"{QTH}" gives an error

Comment: Maybe I could make a new dataframe and put the contents from the csv in this frame?But this seems laborious. Somehow by read_csv I receive not only the data. Instead I seems to get also some csv info as well. This distubs writing to excel.

Comment: What program is providing `ws` and `wb`? Add that information as update to question. As of now you look to be assigning the entire contents of `QTH` to cell `A1`.

Comment: wb = xw.Book(fn)
#ws = wb.sheets["Berechnung"]
ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = dfa
#this works
QTH = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\A6ddd7\l2listen\SLAdddetzA.csv")
ws = wb.sheets["QTH"]
ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = f"{QTH}"
#this mess up the table
wb.save(fn)
wb.close()

Comment: And it is important, that my xlwings workbook do not overwrite other sheets in my wb.

Comment: The problem seems to be, that pandas do not use ";" 

    QTH = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\A69aa7\aalisten\SLTHA.csv",sep = ';',
                   engine = 'python')

The problem is the ";" line terminator. Pandas expected the "," probably

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
 # create excel file
file=pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\SLA.xlsx')
# put csv data in Excel 
QTH.to_excel(file)
# save it
file.save()
```

Comment: Not possible, I need to write to an existing Excel sheet:

Comment: wb = xw.Book(fn)
#ws = wb.sheets["Berechnung"]
ws = wb.sheets["Berechnung"]
ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = dfa
ws["H1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = erg_tab

Comment: QTH.to_excel(your_excel_file,sheet_name='Berechnung', index=False)